# python settingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe donde quiero insertar una nueva columna con los valores `shift()` de otra, sería así:

```
df['new_column'] = df['column'].shift()
```

Me esta dando este warning:

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
> value instead

¿Cuál sería la manera correcta de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

La advertencia `SettingWithCopy` sale cuando hay un indexado encadenado ya que este puede generar resultados inesperados ([Documentación oficial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html))

Si te llega a aparecer, tal como menciona la advertencia para corregirlo hay que utilizar `loc` o `iloc`

La sintaxis de `loc` aparece también en la misma advertencia

```
 .loc[fila,columna]
```

Y para obtener todas las filas de una sola columna podrías hacer ([Documentación de loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html))

```
df['new_column'] = df.loc[:,'column'].shift()
```

Comment: Esto último no ha solucionado el problema, vengo de eliminar columnas duplicadas con la siguiente línea: df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()], y debido a ello ahí crea la copia y con el shift da el problema

Comment: Esa información hubiera sido valiosa al principio... deberías editar tu pregunta e incluir la información faltante así como todos los pasos para reproducir el problema y algunas líneas de tu `dataframe` con las que se pueda reproducir el error. Después de eso puedo revisarlo y editar mi respuesta